# How to take apart message string?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4, elastic-stack

Few days ago I set up my first ELK server to monitor the traffic on my firewall. Logstash is collecting all logs and I can see all in kibana under discover tab. But I noticed that all important information are not listed. How I can take apart message string? I would like to have variable such as sourceip pointing to 10.0.100.26 and destination ip pointing to 100.17.xxx.x

Any idea how I can do this?

JSON code from my last log:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2016.06.13",
  "_type": "syslog",
  "_id": "AVVI5yh_EZJEbJp591pq",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "RT_FLOW_SESSION_CREATE: session created 10.0.100.26/48107->100.17.xxx.x/41427 None xxx.xx.xx.x/20167->100.17.xxx.x/41427 wifi-to-internet-r1 None 17 wifi-to-internet wifi internet 146586 N/A(N/A) ge-0/0/4.0 UNKNOWN UNKNOWN UNKNOWN",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2016-06-13T08:35:56.042Z",
    "type": "syslog",
    "host": "10.0.2.1",
    "syslog_severity_code": 5,
    "syslog_facility_code": 1,
    "syslog_facility": "user-level",
    "syslog_severity": "notice",
    "priority": "14",
    "timestamp": "Jun 13 09:26:50",
    "logsource": "srx",
    "program": "RT_FLOW"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1465806956042
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1465806956042
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is usually done by using the grok filter and defining regular expressions to take apart your message and store it in variables.

Comment: @pandaadb do you know where I can find any information about this? or maybe examples how I can get for example IP address after session created?

Comment: you can use http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ to debug your regexes. This has patterns: https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html is the official docs.